# Disable accelerometer on Blackberry Storm

Tags: blackberry, accelerometer, blackberry-storm

i develop application for Blackberry. In Storm 1 (4.7) and Storm 2 (5.0) i need to disable accelerometer in my application. I want my application does not react to the accelerometer, but that does not affect other applications. Its possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to disable accelerometer but you can lock screen orientation change:

```
// To force portrait view in a BlackBerry API application,
// use code like this before invoking UiApplication.pushScreen()
int directions = Display.DIRECTION_NORTH | Display.DIRECTION_SOUTH;
Ui.getUiEngineInstance.setAcceptableDirections(directions);
```

See [Specifying the orientation and direction of the screen](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Specifying_display_direction_of_screen_647783_11.jsp)